# Alternative to iframe in TizenStudio Web App for Samsung TV Flip Pro

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, webview, tizen

I'm currently developing a web application using TizenStudio for a Samsung TV Flip Pro. In my application, I need to embed and display external web content. Initially, I used an iframe to achieve this, but I've noticed a significant drop in performance when using it.

I also tried using AJAX to fetch and display the content, but I encountered CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) errors, which prevented me from accessing the desired content.

Given these constraints:

- My project is a web app developed in TizenStudio, not a .NET application.
- AJAX throws CORS errors.
- iframe degrades performance.
  Is there an alternative method or approach I can use to embed external web pages into my TizenStudio web app efficiently?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.